# How does PDOStatement::fetchObject set properties before the class is constructed?

Tags: php

When I call [this function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchobject.php), and add a constructor to my class, all my class properties are already set. How is that possible -- I thought you had to construct a class before you could set its properties?

Comment: This appears to be the source https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/pdo/pdo_stmt.c#L1329 for reference

Answer (score 1):

I guess that PDO uses some internal code to create an object without invoking the constructor. However it is possible to instance a new object without calling the constructor even in pure PHP, all you have to do is to deserialize an empty object:

```
class SampleClass {
    private $fld = 'fldValue';

    public function __construct() {
        var_dump(__METHOD__);
    }

    // getters & setters
}

$sc = unserialize(sprintf('O:%d:"%s":0:{}', strlen('SampleClass'), 'SampleClass'));
echo $sc->getFld(); // outputs: fldValue, without calling the construcotr
```

As of PHP 5.4.0+ [`ReflectionClass::newInstanceWithoutConstructor()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.newinstancewithoutconstructor.php) method is available in reflection API.

Comment: This has been possible (creating an object via pdo) at least si ce php 5.2

Comment: Curious. Once I create the object can I still invoke the constructor at a later time? Perhaps by calling `$obj->__construct()` manually?

Comment: @Mark I suppose you can. Just try to do that.

Answer (score 0):

In php, any array can be cast to an object.  My assumption is pdo creates an associative array an then jus casts it.  I dont know if he constuctor is called on cast...

Actually, a cast isnt the right word, a conversion occurs behind the scenes. Read this. Blurb on what happens: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php